# Hibernate Envers with Spring Boot - configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to setup Hibernate Envers to work with my Spring Boot application.

I've included the Envers dependency and added **@Audited** annotations and it works fine, but I'm unable to configure specific Envers properties, Spring Boot doesn't seem to pick them up.

Specifically, I've tried to set the different db schema for audit tables by putting these to **application.properties**, but without luck:

```
hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

or

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

Neither of these work. Does anyone know how to set these?

**EDIT.**

As M. Deinum suggested I tried:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

and it worked!

Comment: Prefix with `spring.jpa.properties` instead. Try `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit`. See  also the [Spring Boot reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties).

Comment: I made it into an answer, please accept (and up vote if you like).

Comment: How did you manage to create envers tables?

Comment: Well, I had spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop set. So every time hibernate creates my tables automatically.

Comment: @Milan Put your answer in answer section, I found your answer after answering your question :)

Comment: Just did http://stackoverflow.com/a/31028233/3603834

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For all those configuration settings that aren't by default available you can specify them by simply prefixing them with `spring.jpa.properties`. Those properties will be added, as is, to the `EntityManagerFactory` (as JPA Properties).

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=app_audit
```

Adding the above to the `application.properties` will add the properties and should configure Hibernate Envers.

This is also documented in the Spring Boot [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties).

Links

1. [Configure JPA properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties)
2. [Envers Properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4079)

Comment: Considering all info, is therefore the 'org' part optional?

Answer (score 5):

Looking through the HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration class I can't see any support for envers properties. The following might not be the best solution but nevertheless your can give it a try.

In order to have Spring Boot support the envers properties you have to:

1. override the current AutoConfiguration class that Spring Boot uses to configure the Hibernate properties, so it will read the envers properties from your property files.
   This will read the **spring.jpa.hibernate.envers.default_schema** from your file and add it to the properties of the **entityManagerFactoryBean**:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class HibernateEnversAutoConfiguration extends HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration {

      private RelaxedPropertyResolver environment;

      public HibernateEnversAutoConfiguration() {
          this.environment = null;
      }

      @Override
      public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
          super.setEnvironment(environment);
          this.environment = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "spring.jpa.hibernate.");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
          super.configure(entityManagerFactoryBean);
          Map<String, Object> properties = entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap();
          properties.put("hibernate.envers.default_schema", this.environment.getProperty("envers.default_schema"));
      }
   }
   ```
2. exclude the original HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration that Spring Boot uses and add your own as a bean so it will be replaced:

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.gabrielruiu.test")
   @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.gabrielruiu.test")
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gabrielruiu.test")
   @Configuration
   public class Main {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
     }

       @Bean
       public HibernateEnversAutoConfiguration hibernateEnversAutoConfiguration() {
           return new HibernateEnversAutoConfiguration();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

For those using **MySQL** and **Spring Boot**, the suggestion of using:

`spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema=yourAuditSchema` will not work.

Use this instead:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog=yourAuditSchema
```

Answer (score 4):

I use with yaml format:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
          org:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: false
                envers:
                    audit_table_suffix: AUDIT
                    revision_field_name: NRO_ID_REVISAO_AUDITORIA
                    revision_type_field_name: TPO_REVISAO_AUDITORIA
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you